# At the Massacre at Hardhome, in Game of Thrones, why did the slain immediately become wights?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At Battle of Hardhome, the slain immediately turned into wights. Yet other dead people, e.g. Jon Snow, didn't become a wight the moment he died<sup>1</sup> and had time to be carried indoors.

Other characters at Castle Black talked about burning dead bodies, even when they were on the south side of the Wall<sup>2</sup> at the time, as they were inside Castle Black IIRC.

---

<sub>1. This happened perhaps because he was south of the Wall?</sub>

<sub>2. Castle Black is barely south of the Wall</sub>

Comment: I think the idea is that the magic is more "concentrated" or powerful because the corpses at Hardhome are in the immediate presence of the Night King, so he animates the bodies directly rather than just letting the magic of the North do it's work at the normal pace.

Comment: Are you safe from zombification long term if you get killed inside Castle Black because it's south of the wall? That is, does the scary magic start immediately north of the wall, or on top of it, or is it unsafe to even be near the wall but on the south side of it?

Comment: @VapedCrusader - good point!

Comment: At the start of the very first ever episode, weren't there some chopped up dead bodies in the forest that very soon vanished, presumably because they woke up as zombies and then went for a walk, rather than the bodies being taken off by something/someone. Is that correct? Anyway, they disappeared pretty quickly. Wasn't it night time? Did that make a difference? This doesn't necessarily help understand Hardhome at all, possibly the contrary.

Comment: The Wall is a magical barrier as well as a physical one, so I strongly suspect that the re-animation stops at the wall. IIRC the only wights that we see south of the wall are the members of the Nights Watch who reanimate after being brought back to Castle Black, but were killed north of the wall(meaning that it can take at least that long for them to come back). In the books, there's also a re-animated hand that they try to bring to Kings Landing, but it rots too quickly.

Comment: Good point. We don't see any dead bodies coming alive who were actually_killed_ south of the wall, and where the bodies are later taken by nightfall doesn't seem to be the point. Perhaps they just wanted to get the dead John Snow indoors out of respect, not because they were worried about the time.

Comment: Is there any difference between the terms _“wight”_ and _“zombie”_ ?

Comment: Zombie doesn't exist as an in-universe term.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Night King hadn't worked his "magic" on Jon Snow

### Not all dead immediately become Wights

Remember the scene in Season 5, Episode 9 (*[Hardhome](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Hardhome_(episode))*), where the [Night King](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Night_King) raises his hands and the dead immediately rose as [wights](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wights)? Well, this didn't happen to Jon Snow, and others who've died - not just in or around Castle Black, but anywhere in [the North](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_North), or [Beyond the Wall](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Beyond_the_Wall).

### How does this even work?

We have no idea how the Night King's magic even works:

- What's its proximity?
- How long can you be dead for before you can be risen?
- Is it only the Night King that can raise wights or *any* [White Walker](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers)?

### The facts

What we *do* know is that

- **The process is not automatic. Someone or something needs to perform some special magical act to re-animate the corpses.**
- The corpses need to be dead first - we haven't seen anybody who's fully alive be reanimated as a wight. Including show!Coldhands ([Benjen Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Benjen_Stark#Season_6)).
- Even animals can be reanimated as wights (but again must be dead first).
- Those who have died in the vicinity of the Night King *can* be reanimated immediately, as seen in *Hardhome*.
- The Wall has magical wards to protect it, similar to the [Cave of the Three-Eyed Raven](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Cave_of_the_three-eyed_raven)

  - You will remember that the Night King couldn't penetrate or find Bran and co whilst hidden in the Cave (Season 6, Episode 5 - *[The Door](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Door)*), since it was protected by some sort of magical ward. Well, the Wall seems to have some similar magical wards; so the Night King might not have been able to get to Jon Snow at that time

---

<sup>**Further reading**:</sup>

- [Why do dead bodies only reanimate beyond the Wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133653/21267)
- [Can white walkers and wights pass through the gates on the wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133658/21267)

Comment: To talk about the obvious: Maybe the Night King does not feel like performing his magic trick every other minute like some circus animal or annoying yet cute child. Maybe he does it only once every night before going to sleep around midnight.

Comment: In addition to what Mooz said, I would also point out that Jon Snow wasn't killed by a wight or white walker. He was stabbed by living, breathing mortal men. All of the bodies we've seen converted to wights were killed by white walkers.